# Make a div a appear and stay after parent div has been clicked on using CSS

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I would like a div (currently `display:hidden;`) to appear after the parent div has been clicked on, and stay there using CSS.

I have currently made it appear when "clicked on" with `:active`, but as soon as I let go of the mouse's button the div disappears.

How can i Make the Div stay in place after it's been clicked on?

I have tried with `:visited` and `:focus` with no luck, any suggestions?

I am new at this so pretty sure I am making a mistake somewhere here. It would be even better if the div went away if clicked on parent div once more.

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.container .l-col, .r-col {
display: none;
}

.container {
cursor: pointer;
}

.container:active .l-col {
display: block;
clear: left;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}

.container:active .r-col {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="portfolio" class="container">
<h2>Parent Element</h2>
<div class="l-col">
<h3>Left Col</h3>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
<div class="r-col">
<h3>Right Col</h3>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use javascript?

Comment: There's no `click` event in css, so either you have to use JS or put some try it with labels, inputs and `:checked` selector.

Comment: I believe that you can make it appear when you click on it with css, but I am not very sure about making it so if you click again, it goes away. I believe the easiest way to do this would be with javascript.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript/jQuery to change the class of the div that is to be shown.  Unlike a programming language like JavaScript, CSS does not have variables to keep track of things.

Comment: Have to have Javascript. You could add onlick="$(this).show()" event to your div but that's JQuery/Javascript as well.

Comment: I am really new at using CSS and HTML and even more so at Java.
I am not very good at Java and so I thought there was a way to make it happen with something like ":visited" or something similar. 

If there is no way around it I might have to jump start with some Java like accordion sort of thing.

Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript... two different languages.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

 I guess I am just still learning everything including the actual differences and details of the various languages. Thanks for your time looking at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save a lot of time and effort using - [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $(".accordion").show().accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
            animate: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            },
        });
    })
    </script>
```

Note that you can style this plugin any way you like,

```
.accordion {/* some style*/}

.ui-accordion-content {/* some style*/}

.accordion h6 {/* some style*/}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/M3mEX/) that shows how I've abused the accordion widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have started playing around with the Accordion and seems to be working, it was easier than I thought it would.

If you don't mind me asking: What other attributes other than "duration and easing" can be selected?
Thanks again

Comment: Here is the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ There are a lot of options/attributes.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't have the functionality that you are looking for. You're going to have to use JavaScript.

Here's some JavaScript to get you started. Place this before the `</body>` end tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("portfolio").onclick = function(){
         this.className = "container-clicked";
    };
</script>
```

And then add styles for the `container-clicked` class.

```
.container-clicked .l-col{
    display:block;
    ...
}
.container-clicked .r-col{
    display:block;
    ...
}
```

Also, a couple points: I believe that the :visited psuedo-class is not working for you because .container is not a link. However, if it was a link, then the :visited styles would stay after page refreshes, which I don't think is what you are looking for.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer I really appreciate it. I have the accordion working now but this is great to start understanding more about JS. I wish I could pick both answers. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 animations to achieve your goal, but it won't be cross-browser compatible..  IE users will lose out on this..

```
/* <yourstylesheet>.css */
@keyframes box_appear
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes box_appear/* Firefox */
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes box_appear /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-o-keyframes box_appear /* Opera */
{
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}

.make_me_appear
{
animation: box_appear 5s;
-moz-animation: box_appear 5s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: box_appear 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation: box_appear 5s; /* Opera */
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('<youroutsideelementsidhere>').onclick = function() {
    // Apply the class to the child elements here.
}

</script>
```

Comment: CSS3 animations are much faster than javascript and are less cpu-intensive.

Check this for more information.
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/